# python regular expressions - how to replace multiple capture groups with items from a list

Tags: python, regex, loops

There are many answers here on regex but none of them meet my need to loop over multiple matches and substitute a capture with successive items from a list.

I've searched the official docs but, to be honest, some of the explanations and examples are simply too advanced and complex for me to grasp.  So far I've worked out how to capture multiple groups and name them but I am stuck on how to insert a different list item into each.

---

Pseudo code example...

```
for first_match group:
    insert list_item 1

for second_match group:
    insert list_item 2

for third_match group :
    insert list_item 3
```

---

Simplified code example (my real script has a dozen or more matches)

The string:

```
"Substitute a **list_item** here, Substitute a **list_item** here, Substitute a **list_item** here"
```

The regular expression:

```
\w.*(?P<first_match>list_item)\W.*\W.*(?P<second_match>list_item)\W.*\W.*(?P<third_match>list_item)
```

The list

```
["first_item", "second_item", "third_item"]
```

What I'm hoping to achieve looks like this:

```
"Substitute a **first_item** here, Substitute a **second_item** here, Substitute a **third_item** here"
```

---

I could also achieve this with un named groups but naming gives more readability.

Comment: Why a regular expression? Is there a specific reason? There are a lot of other ways to achieve this as well, so I'm just curious

Comment: If you use regex, insertion requires capturing in-between data. Don't know Python, but in Perl it might be done like Find: `(?<Before_item1>\w.)(?<Before_item2>\W.\W.)(?<Before_item3>\W.\W.*)` Replace: `$+{Before_item1}$list[1]$+{Before_item2}$list[2]$+{Before_item3}$list[3]`

Comment: So many ways to skin a cat with Python.  As a scripting novice it's hard to know which tool is best for a job.  Up til now I've shied away from regular expressions 'cause they sound complex and mathematical and look like a bunch of hierogliphics.  However now I've rolled up my sleeves and had a little success, up to the point where I started wondering whether regular expressions were compatible with looping in the way that I describe above.  I see now from Rawing's answer that they can indeed cope but I'd love to hear your suggestion for better/quicker/easier way to scalp this feline.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be achieved using the [start() and end() functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start).

```
import re

string= "Substitute a **list_item** here, Substitute a **list_item** here, Substitute a **list_item** here"
pattern= r'\w.*(?P<first_match>list_item)\W.*\W.*(?P<second_match>list_item)\W.*\W.*(?P<third_match>list_item)'

list= ["first_item", "second_item", "third_item"]


result= ''
i= 0
last_match= 0
match= re.match(pattern, string)
for count in xrange(len(match.groups())): # for each group...
    result+= string[last_match:match.start(i+1)] # add all text up to the start of the group
    result+= list[i] # add the next list item
    last_match= match.end(i+1)
    i+= 1
result+= string[last_match:] # finally, add all text after the last group

print result
```

Comment: Very happy at the speedy replies.. thanks peeps.
I like this because it's easy to read and I can follow the logic AND it works in my IDE, with the simplified example. However I'm struggling to get it to work in my actual code but I'm banging away at it, determined to make it run, so thanks heaps.
I am getting this error:
>>>
for count in xrange(len(match.groups())): # for each group...

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: @Hazy: That means your pattern didn't match the string. The `match` object is None in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a mapping to replace?

```
def mapping_replace(s):
    import re
    mapping = \ # allows us to continue to the next line
    {
        'first_item': '"Hi there"',
        'second_item': '"waddup"',
        'third_item': '"potato"'
    }

    # for each key in the map
    for key in mapping.iterkeys():
        # replace any 'key' found with the 'value' that corresponds with it
        s = re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % key, mapping[key], s, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    return s

print mapping_replace('first_item substitute a first_item here, a second_item here and a third_item here... first_item') # prints "Hi there" substitute a "Hi there" here, a "waddup" here and a "potato" here "Hi there"
```

The `\b` checks to see that there's a word boundary. If you're not concerned with that you can just match the key and then there doesn't need to be a space, i.e `first_itemyaa` would see `first_item` and replace it with `"Hi there"` for `"Hi there"yaa`

Comment: I appreciate your neat example, which I'm sure will be useful in future but it won't work for me in my current task because my 'keys' are all identical.  I need to replace them sequentially with items from my list.